# looping through a named vector

Tags: r, iteration

i am trying to figure out how to loop through a named vector of regression coefficients. i want to loop through the vector and detect whether or not a coefficient name contains the string `'country'`. if it does, i want to append the corresponding value to an empty vector. i already solved this using `dplyr` tools, but i also want to do it using a `for` loop.

this is what my data looks like:

```
str(co2_per_cap_model$coefficients)
 Named num [1:164] -0.0511 0.3289 1.2352 3.0743 0.8654 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:164] "(Intercept)" "time" "countryAlbania" "countryAlgeria" ...
```

this is the loop i've been tinkering with. any advice? thank you in advance.

```
storage <- c()

for(coeff in co2_per_cap_model$coefficients){
  
    if(str_detect(names(co2_per_cap_model$coefficients), 'country')){
      
      storage <- c(coeff, storage)
      
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: try to use the append function it goes like storage <- append(storage,coeff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to create some reproducible data. Then just use `grep`:

```
set.seed(42)
coef <- 1:25
names(coef) <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 25, replace=TRUE)
str(coef)
#  Named int [1:25] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:25] "A" "E" "A" "A" ...
idx <- grep("A", names(coef))
coef[idx]
#  A  A  A  A  A  A  A 
#  1  3  4  9 11 17 18
```